# Draper Decorator spec not able to use Devise current_user method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, draper

I have a `PostDecorator` class in `app/decorators/post_decorator.rb`.
It has a method that calls Devise's `current_user` method. It looks like this:

```
class PostDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  def voter
    h.current_user
  end
end
```

I have a `PostDecorator` spec in `spec/decorators/post_decorator_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PostDecorator, type: :decorator do
  let(:post) { FactoryGirl.create(:post) }
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { allow(helper).to receive(:current_user) { user } }

  describe 'voter' do
    it 'returns the current_user' do
      expect(post.voter).to eq user
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this I get an undefined method error:

```
<Draper::HelperProxy:0x007fb1c4f85890 ... does not implement: current_user
```

Gem Versions:

- draper (1.4.0)
- rspec-rails (3.4.1)
- devise (3.5.5)

Also I should note everything in my `app/lib` directory is auto loaded. In `application.rb` I have `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to Draper.
Decorator is unable to access helper methods after sending an ActionMailer email.

[This is an open issue on Draper's GitHub](https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/655)

To solve this I just modified the User Factory by adding a `confirmed_at`:

```
factory :user do
  ...
  confirmed_at DateTime.now
end
```

This way Devise won't send a Confirmation email.

Comment: just an observation, but his question seems to have nothing to do with a mailer of any kind as far as i can tell. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @MilesStanfield If the user object does not have a confirmed_at value then Devise will kick out a confirmation email. The issue I linked too documents it better.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I think you need to do.

1.) Add devise test helpers to your decorator tests,

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :decorator
end
```

2.) you actually need to sign_in to expect `post.voter` to eq an actual users

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PostDecorator, type: :decorator do
  let(:post) { FactoryGirl.create(:post) }
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    sign_in user
  end

  describe '.voter' do
    it 'returns the current_user' do
      expect(post.voter).to eq user
    end
  end
end
```